# Multiple steps in runandload

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

How is it possible to perform multiple processing steps for one layer without creating additional ones?

I wanted to add several fields to attribute table using qgis:fieldcalculator but every time it works new layer is created. Is it possible to redirect output from first .runalg to second and so on until getting final result without additional layers?

```
first = processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', 'S1_PROJ_1992[PTS]', 'X_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number', None)
second = processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', first['OUTPUT'], 'Y_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number', None)
processing.runandload('qgis:fieldcalculator', second['OUTPUT'], 'Y_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number*(-1)', )
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @MarkZ! Ideally when asking a question about coding, you should include what you have :). Saying that, replace `runandload` with just `runalg` and when calling the _qgis:fieldcalculator_ function, use `None` as the output at each step excluding the final step where you can specify the path of the final output and use `runandload` to load it immediately.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, i updated OP.

Actually that brings up second question, how to adress to layer from .runalg since it is not (?) saved anywhere?

Comment: use `first['OUTPUT']` and  `second ['OUTPUT']` in your second runalg and runandload method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following where you can call each step of the field calculator as an input to the next step. As each step saves the output temporarily in a dictionary, you can call it using `['OUTPUT_LAYER']` :

```
layerOut = 'layer.shp'
first = processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', 'S1_PROJ_1992[PTS]', 'X_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number', None)
second = processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', first['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'Y_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number', None)
processing.runandload('qgis:fieldcalculator', second['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'Y_2000', 0, 10, 1, True, '@row_number*(-1)', layerOut)
```

Comment: @MarkZ - Most welcome, glad it helped :)